# Android-get a grid view item by coordinate

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gridview

I have looked at other questions that are related, but I can't seem to find an answer. I am getting an item's coordinates then trying to get adjacent items using their coordinates. Is there a way to get an item by it's coordinates(I would create an instance and assign the item to the instance). If it matters, I'm using ImageViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method in Android API. If I understand right, you need to calculate the `position` from `x,y` coordinates:

```
position = y*cols + x
```

where cols is the number of items in 1 row.
Then just use the grid's adapter `getView` method with your calculated `position`

Answer (score 1):

There is an API in AbsListView called pointToPosition();

```
int position = gridView.pointToPosition((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY()));
```